# Customize Pushover Notification from Gmail Message Filter

Tags: json, api, filter, gmail, push

I am currently using a Gmail filter to forward particular email messages to the Pushover notification service which then sends a notification to my iPhone with the message content.

My issue is that I only care about one line in the email message (its a shift alert notification) that is the same every time. Is there a good way to just get this line sent in the notification service? I need to set up some sort of 'middleman' to edit the content of the message before it gets sent to Pushover as both Gmail and Pushover have no way to edit the content. Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Elliott

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using my webhost's cpanel forward to program feature to create a PHP pipe that trims the message and uses CURL to send it to Pushover's service!